# How to use Poco C++ in proxy environment (using HTTPStreamFactory)

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

The following code is not working in Proxy environment set in internet options.
POCO library example does not show,how to do. Is there any solution?
I am using latest poco library

```
using Poco::URIStreamOpener;
using Poco::StreamCopier;
using Poco::Path;
using Poco::URI;
using Poco::SharedPtr;
using Poco::Exception;
using Poco::Net::HTTPStreamFactory;
using Poco::Net::FTPStreamFactory;

class WebInitializer
{
public:
    WebInitializer()
    {
        HTTPStreamFactory::registerFactory();
        FTPStreamFactory::registerFactory();
    }

    ~WebInitializer()
    {
        HTTPStreamFactory::unregisterFactory();
        FTPStreamFactory::unregisterFactory();
    }
};

void Download(std::string host, std::string path, std::string targetFilePath)
    {   
        WebInitializer webInitializer;
        std::string sUrl = host + path;
        URI uri(sUrl);          
        std::shared_ptr<std::istream> pStr(URIStreamOpener::defaultOpener().open(uri));
        ofstream outputfile;
        outputfile.exceptions(std::ofstream::badbit | std::ofstream::failbit);

        outputfile.open(targetFilePath, std::ios_base::binary);
        StreamCopier::copyStream(*pStr.get(), outputfile);
        outputfile.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See [testcase](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/testsuite/src/HTTPStreamFactoryTest.cpp#L83).

```
HTTPStreamFactory factory("myproxy", port);
URI uri(host);
std::auto_ptr<std::istream> pStr(factory.open(uri));
std::istream& rs = s.receiveResponse(response);
ofstream outputfile;
outputfile.open(targetFilePath, std::ios_base::binary);
StreamCopier::copyStream(*pStr.get(), outputfile);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, what is "myproxy" here, do I have to get the proxy string from system depends on OS, will it work on redirection scenario?, Is it assumes default authentication for proxy?

Comment: "myproxy" is your proxy server. See [testProxyAuth](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/testsuite/src/HTTPClientSessionTest.cpp#L262) for authentication example.

Comment: if my application is run on some customer machine, I need to put their proxy server name, am I right? This may work on my test case

Comment: I don't know what yours or your customer's system setup looks like. Proxy can be running anywhere between localhost and the rest of the world.

Comment: Alex, I have used WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(&ieProxyConfig) to get proxy and pass it on to HTTPClientSession s(host);
s.setProxy(ieproxy, port); it works, but redirection case fails

Comment: Because HTTPClient does not have built-in support redirect like [HTTPStreamFactory](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/src/HTTPStreamFactory.cpp#L119). You will have to handle it yourself.

Comment: But you can also use proxy with HTTPStreamFactory, look at the [test cases](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/testsuite/src/HTTPStreamFactoryTest.cpp#L43)

Comment: I have updated the answer to use factory with proxy. You may want to replace auto_ptr with unique_ptr, but I did not test it.

Comment: I have changed my implementation , I put this solution as one below

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution to this problem. in this uri_proxy class implementation is not shown which is OS specific, one can easily implement.

```
int redirectiocount = 0;
        bool found= false;
        while (redirectiocount < 10 && !found)
        {
            HTTPClientSession session(resolvedURI.getHost(), resolvedURI.getPort());
            session.setProxy(uri_proxy.getHost(), uri_proxy.getPort());
            session.setTimeout(Poco::Timespan(400, 0));
            std::string path(resolvedURI.getPathAndQuery());
            if (path.empty()) path = "/";
            HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path);
            session.sendRequest(request);
            HTTPResponse response;
            std::istream& rs = session.receiveResponse(response);
            bool moved = (response.getStatus() == HTTPResponse::HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY ||
                response.getStatus() == HTTPResponse::HTTP_FOUND ||
                response.getStatus() == HTTPResponse::HTTP_SEE_OTHER ||
                response.getStatus() == HTTPResponse::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
            if (moved)
            {

                resolvedURI.resolve(response.get("Location"));
                redirectiocount++;
                //throw URIRedirection(resolvedURI.toString());
            }
            else if (response.getStatus() == HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK)
            {
                found = true;               
                ofstream outputfile;
                outputfile.open(outfilePath, std::ios_base::binary);
                StreamCopier::copyStream(rs, outputfile);
                outputfile.close();

            }
            else
            {
                std::string error(response.getReason());
                std::string urlstring = "-" + uri.toString();
                error += urlstring;
                throw Poco::SyntaxException(error);
            }
```

Comment: Consider adding the declarations of most of the variables used in the code block if at all possible. Try indenting the code when you put it.